# Loading a Google Charts example with XMLHttpRequest turns the page white

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, google-visualization

We have a page which uses XMLHttpRequests and tries not to reload the page at all. After the user has logged in it should load a chart. Here is the main page: http://pastebin.com/h55Vzuvy
Here is what we are loading as the chart: http://pastebin.com/zDZr3bb6

I realize that the code where the function is called to load chart.php isn't displayed here but it is working properly and simply calls the xmlhttpGet function in the header of the main page.

The page that loads does evaluate Javascript, as I can put an alert and it pops up but the graph simply doesn't load. Any ideas why?

Also, the Chrome JS Debugger says this when I click to load the chart file. I have triple checked to make sure that the div name is being passed to the variables and the error only happens when loading the chart page.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
sethtml
callBackFunction
xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks good at first glance, but this line:

```
document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=content;
```

Looks like it's where you're having the problem.  Most likely 'div' (the id which should be 'auth_status' at this point) is not set right or the DOM was modified and busted up the auth_status div.

I'd recommend testing with:

```
console.log("id: " + div);
```

on the line right before that (so, line 66).  If that shows "auth_status" as the ID like you'd expect, then I'd try typing this in the firebug/chrome js console:

```
document.getElementById(div)
```

to make sure it's still in the DOM.  Good luck!